FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'
 A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector found in modules jetified-imagepipeline-base-2.5.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.5.0) and jetified-stetho-2.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector$DumpInfo found in modules jetified-imagepipeline-base-2.5.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.5.0) and jetified-stetho-2.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector$DumpInfoEntry found in modules jetified-imagepipeline-base-2.5.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.5.0) and jetified-stetho-2.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-26.0-android (com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android) and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0 (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

i change Kotlin version but again i get error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

when I want to run app I get this error
